# Cannot load a base64 encoded image from mysql database using php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a longblob field in mysql database that stores a binary value for a image that i uploaded through my webpage.

I am trying to get the image using

```
  <?php while( $record = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result ) ): ?>
<div>       
       <?php echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($record['image']).'"height="300" width="300"/>'?>
       <br/>
        <?php echo "Title:".htmlentities( $record['title'] ); ?>
        <br/>
      <?php echo "Genre:".htmlentities($record['genre']); ?>
      <br/>
      <?php echo "Author:".htmlentities( $record['author'] ); ?>
      <br/>
      <a href="booksEdit.php?id=<?php echo $record['id']; ?>" style="color:#1217b3">Edit</i></a>
      <br/>      
      <a href="books.php?delete=<?php echo $record['id']; ?>" 
      onclick="javascript:confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this project?');" style="color:#1217b3">Delete</i></a>
        </div>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
```

and img tag looks like this in html

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,MlN0YXRlLmpwZw==" height="300" width="300">
```

Comment: We need a bit more information. Could you show us how you upload the image to the database? And a space before `height="300"`, like in your example, would be nice.

Answer (score 3):

You have base64 encoded the image **file name** not the **file contents**

```
MlN0YXRlLmpwZw==
```

actually outputs:

```
2State.jpg
```

When storing it in the database you need to do

```
$imageContent = base64_encode(file_get_contents($file));
```